# How to bind the value in html select option?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to bind the value in html select option and I have the values in a C# model. How do I do this? My html code:

```
 <div class="Div"><span class="label2">values:</span>
    <select id="Binding_values" onchange="values()></select></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and a controller action which will populate this view model and pass it to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.Items = new[]
    {
        // TODO: those values could come from a database for example
        new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "item 1" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "item 2" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "item 3" },
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

inside the corresponding strongly typed view you could use the `DropDownListFor` helper:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.Items)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

and if this dropdown is inside an HTML for posting back to the controller you could have an action that will retrieve the selected value from the model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    // model.SelectedValue will contain the selected value from the dropdown list here
    ...
}
```

Assuming you want to send the selected value to the server immediately after changing the selection in the dropdown without clicking on a form submit button you could give this DropDownList an unique id:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.Items, new { id = "myDdl" })
```

and then subscribe to the `.change()` event of this dropdown using jQuery and submit the containing form:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myDdl').change(function() {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: I think its write, But where is the js?

Comment: Ideally in a separate javascript file. You could add a custom js file that you would reference: `<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/myscript.js")"></script>`.

Comment: Its not, i need the hoe yo link the c# and html.droplist? i am using mvc4 format. i gather value through the javscript post method

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: i am suing mvc4 formate, i have value in c# model but how to pass the request to the mode page from the html page

Comment: I have shown that in my answer => you build a view model, have a controller action that is passing this view model to the view and when the form is submitted you could retrieve the selected value. It's the way ASP.NET MVC is supposed to work.